# How can I get more information from Exception (occurring randomly C# WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, exception

We have a big business application that runs on top of WPF and Entity Framework. The problem is that we are having a issue for the last 2 weeks and can't identify the source of it.

The Exception is being trapped by DispatcherUnhandledException and the information we are getting from the exception (via email) is this:

```
mscorlib: Value cannot be null.
   at System.Threading.Monitor.ReliableEnter(Object obj, Boolean& lockTaken)
   at System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Object obj, Boolean& lockTaken)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize()
```

The exception is being thrown "randomly" 4 or 5 times a day and only from ONE of the 20+ users we have. We can't figure out the problem!. the stack trace is not giving much information and we can't reproduce the problem.

I assume this is happening on a thread, but I can't identify the thread causing the exception as we have a lot of BackgroundWorkers and async stuff!

So, how can I get more information about the exception??

---

**Edit:**

There isn't any InnerExceptions.

Also, the exception is being thrown in intervals of minutes and then hours for example at: 11:41, 11:46, 11:51 then it runs fine till 18:03, 18:07, 18:11 then no exceptions are thrown. The moments in which this minute-intervals are occurring are random too, not related with any load on the servers or the network.

Comment: Is there an `InnerException` that is not being delivered via email?

Comment: no, all the exceptions caught are being sent with their InnerExceptions if any.

Comment: You probably have an exception somewhere in your code which is hidden by some callback in the framework. Try adding catch clauses that log exceptions and then throw; them back in the points of contact with WPF (e.g. in VM setters, in command implementations). Also, if possible send that client the matching PDBs and try to debug remotely (using Visual Studio Remote Debugger).

Comment: Do you just get the exception text via email or a full crash dump? In the latter case, load the crash dump into WinDbg, load [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx), and execute the command `!pe`; this will show you the exception with any inner exceptions. In case you don't have a crash dump, ask your customer to send to one to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is probably happening as part of the Garbage Collection thread.  The Finalize call on the bottom of the stack is the hint, and then that's probably calling EntityConnection.Dispose(false);

The nature of the problem is non-deterministic.  Something may have changed in your environment that it's now happening.

In the finalizer it's really unsafe to be accessing other managed objects.  It looks like ChangeConnectionString is probably trying to use a managed object as a lock, and sometimes when it's in the GC thread the object has already been cleaned up.  That it's doing this is probably a bug in the EntityConnection.

You should be able to avoid this by calling Dispose on your Components, rather than letting the Finalizer get run (enclosing them in using blocks is a great way to ensure this).  With the callstack you have though, it's hard to say much about the nature of the Component that's causing the issue.

If you want to get a local repro, try subclassing your Component objects that are accessing EntityConnections with a class that overrides Finalize (e.g. ~MyComponent()) and throw an Exception in it.  That way you'll get the crash if the GC ever cleans up those objects.

Comment: We have `using` clause in all the EF connections. I'm doing remote debugging now, I never used it before and it looks promising. Thanks for your answer. I will update this thread with more info when available.

Answer (score 1):

the "ReliableEnter value cannot be null" error means that you are trying to lock on an object which is set to null.

Find where the object is being set to null.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen; in my case I was disposing a `SemaphoreSlim` too early.

My code was something like

```
using (var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1))
{
    //... start task that will call semaphore.Release()
    return func(); // this in turn calls semaphore.WaitAsync(timeout);
}
```

Since I was not `await`-ing the `Task` returned by `func`, the semaphore was `Dispose`d too early and I was getting the "ReliableEnter value cannot be null" error.